# Do not execute JS if hovering over specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a custom cursor implemented and I do not want this cursor to be visible when `hovering` over the `.header` element.

To achieve this, I've tried:

```js
var isHovered = false;

$('.header').hover(function() {
  isHovered = true;
});

if (isHovered){
  // hovering over .header, don't show cursor
} else {
  // cursor js here
}
```

However, that doesn't work. Working demo below with my attempt commented out:

```js
/* var isHovered = false;

$('.header').hover(function() {
  isHovered = true;
});
 */

/* if (isHovered) { */

  const customCursor = (e) => {

    const cursor = document.querySelector('.custom-cursor');
    const hoverEl = document.querySelectorAll('a.button')
    const {
      pageX: posX,
      pageY: posY
    } = e;

    const runMouseOver = () => {
      cursor.style.transform = 'scale(2)';
    };
    hoverEl.forEach(hover => hover.addEventListener('mouseenter', runMouseOver));

    const runMouseLeave = () => {
      cursor.style.transform = '';
      cursor.style.background = '';
    };
    hoverEl.forEach(hover => hover.addEventListener('mouseleave', runMouseLeave));

    return (
      cursor.style.left = `${posX - 10}px`,
      cursor.style.top = `${posY - 10}px`
    );

  };

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', customCursor);

/* } */
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  cursor: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-black {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.bg-white {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.header{
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #5F249F;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
}

.custom-cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.875rem;
  height: 0.875rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: top 0.0125s ease-in-out, left 0.0125s ease-in-out,
    transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="custom-cursor js-cursor"></div>
  <main>
    <header class="header">
      Header
    </header>
  
    <section class="section-1 bg-black">
       <h1 class="js-cursor-hover">
          Hello world
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section class="section-2 bg-white">
       <h1 class="js-cursor-hover">
          Hello world
      </h1>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: From a cursory glance, the main issue with your code is probably that you keep adding new event listeners, dozens, hundreds, to the elements.

Comment: The first problem is that you keep adding and removing listeners from a list of buttons *every time you move the mouse*! This is bad practice. Better to define the mouseover / mouse out listeners outside of the mouse move function. Then on every move you can check if the mouseover of the header has been triggered or not.

Comment: It may be interesting to set a custom cursor image using CSS. Then you can simply set `cursor:pointer` on the header. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: Here's one way to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/q7sr8u9p/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would only attach the mouse move listener to sections.

```
let els = document.querySelectorAll('section');
els.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mousemove', customCursor));
```

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.custom-cursor');

const runMouseOver = () => cursor.style.transform = 'scale(2)';

const runMouseLeave = () => {
  cursor.style.transform = '';
  cursor.style.background = '';
};

const customCursor = (e) => {

  const {
      pageX: posX,
      pageY: posY
  } = e;

  return (
      cursor.style.left = `${posX - 10}px`,
      cursor.style.top = `${posY - 10}px`
  );

};

let els = document.querySelectorAll('section');
els.forEach(el => 
           {
              el.addEventListener('mousemove', customCursor);
              const links = el.querySelectorAll('a.button')
              links.forEach(link => 
                           {
                             link.addEventListener('mouseenter', runMouseOver);
                             link.addEventListener('mouseleave', runMouseLeave);
                           });
           });
           
const header = document.querySelector('header');
header.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => cursor.style.visibility = 'hidden');
header.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => cursor.style.visibility = 'visible');
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  cursor: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-black {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.bg-white {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.header{
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #5F249F;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
}

.custom-cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.875rem;
  height: 0.875rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: top 0.0125s ease-in-out, left 0.0125s ease-in-out,
    transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="custom-cursor js-cursor"></div>
  <main>
    <header class="header">
      Header
    </header>
  
    <section class="section-1 bg-black">
       <h1 class="js-cursor-hover">
          Hello world
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section class="section-2 bg-white">
       <h1 class="js-cursor-hover">
          Hello world
      </h1>
      <a class="button" href=''>link</a>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

I have also moved around the `addListener`s for the anchors, to make sure they're only attached once.

Comment: In your demo, when hovering over to the header, it leaves the custom cursor attatched. Is there a way to hide it if hovering over anything other than a `section` and then make it reappear when hover on a `section`?

Comment: @Freddy I've made a change to the code to manage that

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already got an eventlistener on `mousemove`, you can get the position and element that the mouse is over using [`Document.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint):

```js
var x = event.clientX, y = e.clientY;
var hover = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

if (hover.tagName === 'HEADER') {
  document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
}
```

```js
const customCursor = (e) => {
  
    var x = event.clientX, y = e.clientY;
    var hover = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

    if (hover.tagName === 'HEADER') {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'unset';
    } else {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'none';
  
      const cursor = document.querySelector('.custom-cursor');
      const hoverEl = document.querySelectorAll('a.button')
      const {
        pageX: posX,
        pageY: posY
      } = e;

      const runMouseOver = () => {
        cursor.style.transform = 'scale(2)';
      };
      hoverEl.forEach(hover => hover.addEventListener('mouseenter', runMouseOver));

      const runMouseLeave = () => {
        cursor.style.transform = '';
        cursor.style.background = '';
      };
      hoverEl.forEach(hover => hover.addEventListener('mouseleave', runMouseLeave));

      return (
        cursor.style.left = `${posX - 10}px`,
        cursor.style.top = `${posY - 10}px`
      );
    }

  };

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', customCursor);

/* } */
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  cursor: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-black {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

.bg-white {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.header{
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #5F249F;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
}

.custom-cursor {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.875rem;
  height: 0.875rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: top 0.0125s ease-in-out, left 0.0125s ease-in-out,
    transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="custom-cursor js-cursor"></div>
  <main>
    <header class="header">
      Header
    </header>
  
    <section class="section-1 bg-black">
       <h1 class="js-cursor-hover">
          Hello world
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section class="section-2 bg-white">
       <h1 class="js-cursor-hover">
          Hello world
      </h1>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```